# Generated ArcGIS tile cache ignores DEM hillshade effect?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, tiles, hillshade

I'm attempting to generate a tile cache in ArcGIS 10.3 where one of the input layers is a DEM raster. The resulting tile cache displays all layers as expected, except for the raster layer. The output tile images show the raster as if it had all the correct settings but simply seems to ignore the hillshade effect that has been applied. The images below illustrate how the raster is originally symbolised (left) vs how it is showing in the tile cache (right).

---

Min-max stretch - Expected vs Actual

[image: Min-max stretch - Expected]
[image: Min-max stretch - Actual]

---

No stretch - Expected vs Actual

[image: No stretch - Expected]
[image: No stretch - Actual]

---

The resulting tiles do seem to take into consideration at least some of the stretched raster settings (e.g. the gradient, stretch type, etc), just not the hillshade.

Should this be happening?

Comment: How did you apply the hillshade effect?

Comment: I applied it I through the symbology tab in the properties window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. Instead of applying the hillshade effect through the symbology tab in the layers properties window, adding a function to the raster in the Image Analysis window seems to be the correct way to get a hillshade effect working in a tile cache export.

First highlight the correct raster at the top of the window and click the Add Function button.

[image]

Next right click and apply the hillshade function to your raster.
[image]